# AngularJS : How to say to a directive to clone scope?

Tags: scope, angularjs

I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/honzajde/u7tAs/2/), and can not make this work. I believe that the reason resides in that two li elements with a custom directive edit-in-place share scope. 
The solution would be to say to the directive to create a copy of the scope that binds on the parent - can transclude help?

```
angular.module('bla', [])
    .directive('editInPlace', ['$parse','$compile', function($parse, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attribs) {
            var inputStart = '<input style="border: 2 solid black" name="inPlaceInput" style="display:none" value="';
            var inputEnd = '">';

            scope.editModeAccessor = $parse(attribs.editInPlace);
            scope.modelAccessor = $parse(attribs.ngBind);

            scope.$watch(attribs.editInPlace, function(newValue, oldValue){
                if (newValue){
                    console.debug("click");
                    console.debug("value: " + scope.modelAccessor(scope));
                    var inputHtml = inputStart + scope.modelAccessor(scope) + inputEnd;
                    element.after(inputHtml);
                    jQuery(element).hide();
                    scope.inputElement = jQuery("input[name=inPlaceInput]");
                    scope.inputElement.show();
                    scope.inputElement.focus();
                    scope.inputElement.bind("blur", function() {
                        blur();
                    });
                } else {
                    blur();
                }
            });

            function blur(){
                console.debug("blur secondary");
                if (scope.inputElement){
                    console.debug("blur secondary inputElement found");
                    var value = scope.inputElement.val();
                    console.debug("input value: "+ value);
                    scope.inputElement.remove();
                    jQuery(element).show();
                    scope.editModeAccessor.assign(scope, false);
                    scope.modelAccessor.assign(scope, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
                            }]);

function ContactsCtrl($scope, $timeout){
    $scope.contacts = [{number:'+25480989333', name:'sharon'},{number:'+42079872232', name:''}];
    $scope.editMode = false;
    var editedId;
    $scope.edit = function(id){
        $scope.editMode = true;
        jQuery("#"+id).hide();
        editedId = id;
        //TODO show delete button
    }
    $scope.$watch('editMode', function(newValue, oldValue){
        if (!newValue && editedId){
            jQuery("#"+editedId).show();
        }
    });
}


<div ng-app="bla">
<div ng-controller="ContactsCtrl">
<h4>Contacts</h4>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
        <span edit-in-place="editMode" ng-bind="contact.number"></span>
        <span edit-in-place="editMode" ng-bind="contact.name"></span>
        <span id="{{$index}}" ng-click="edit($index)"><i class="icon-edit">CLICKtoEDIT</i></span>
    </li>
</ul>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think cloning the scope is not the best solution.

When creating a directive in angular, you should encapsulate **all** the functionality within the directive. You should also avoid mixing jQuery in when you don't have to. Most of the time (as in this case) you're just introducing unnecessary complexity. Lastly, classes are the best way of controlling display, rather than the `style` attribute on an element.

I took the liberty of rewriting your directive in a more "angular" way - with no jQuery. As you can see from the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/NDFHg/), it is simpler and cleaner. Also, it works!

This directive can be easily modified to add lots of additional awesome functionality.

```
app.directive( 'editInPlace', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { value: '=' },
    template: '<span ng-click="edit()" ng-bind="value"></span><input ng-model="value"></input>',
    link: function ( $scope, element, attrs ) {
      // Let's get a reference to the input element, as we'll want to reference it.
      var inputElement = angular.element( element.children()[1] );

      // This directive should have a set class so we can style it.
      element.addClass( 'edit-in-place' );

      // Initially, we're not editing.
      $scope.editing = false;

      // ng-click handler to activate edit-in-place
      $scope.edit = function () {
        $scope.editing = true;

        // We control display through a class on the directive itself. See the CSS.
        element.addClass( 'active' );

        // And we must focus the element. 
        // `angular.element()` provides a chainable array, like jQuery so to access a native DOM function, 
        // we have to reference the first element in the array.
        inputElement[0].focus();
      };

      // When we leave the input, we're done editing.
      inputElement.prop( 'onblur', function() {
        $scope.editing = false;
        element.removeClass( 'active' );
      });
   }
};
```

});

Comment: Hi Josh, first let me thank you very much. Your solution is elegant and working. However my original intention was to have a directive that can be used to "decorate" any element to make it editable. The second requirement was to in time of click on edit button both fields being inputs. Therefore I have to play with it alittle bit and see if it actually solves my problem before I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Great answer Josh! There are nice tutorial videos about making something along the lines of in-place editing as well: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKJDHnXaKTY&list=UUKW92i7iQFuNILqQOUOCrFw&index=14

Comment: This is already linked on SO. But these examples tells u nothing about  how difficult it is to get angular working. You better linked issues like [this] (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1267). I lost quite few hours before I found the answer when playing with models.

Comment: Your answer, Josh, is a nice tutorial on writing angularjs directives. But it does not answer my question. I rephrased my question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172060/tricky-scope-binding-in-agularjs-directives] (here).

Comment: The actual html contains edit-in-place element, is it intentional?

Comment: @user271996 Yes, I changed the directive from an `attribute` to an `element` (that's the `restrict` line in the directive). It was personal preference, but it will work fine as an attribute too: http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/NDFHg/6/. Why did you create a separate question rather than expand on your requirements here? With more info I'd be happy to modify the directive...