# Tricky scope binding in angularjs directives

Tags: angularjs

I want to write 'edit in place' directive in angularjs. 
I want that directive is reusable, therefore I have following requirements on the directive:

1. it must be an attirbute that can deocorate any element, that makes sense (div,span,li)
2. it must support edit button, clicking on that will change set ot displayd elements into input fileds. Typically properties of one object, e.g. contact (number, name)

I disocvere trickery behaviour of scope visibility in the directive that can be seen in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/honzajde/ZgNbU/1/.

1. Comenting out in the directive: template and scope -> contact.number and contact.name are displayed
2. Comenting out in the directive: scope -> contact.number only is displayed
3. Not commenting out anything -> nothing is displayed

=> when both are commented out just adding template to the directive makes it render contact.number even though template is not used.

I am asking what are the rules of the game?

```
<div>
  <div ng-controller="ContactsCtrl">
    <h2>Contacts</h2>
    <br />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
            <span edit-in-place="" ng-bind="contact.number"></span> | 
            <span edit-in-place="" >{{contact.name}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <br />
    <p>Here we repeat the contacts to ensure bindings work:</p>
    <br />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
            {{contact.number}} | {{contact.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>


var app = angular.module( 'myApp', [] );

app.directive( 'editInPlace', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    //scope: { contact:"=" },    
    template: '<span ng-click="edit()" ng-bind="value"></span><input ng-model="value"></input>',
    link: function ( $scope, element, attrs ) {
      // Let's get a reference to the input element, as we'll want to reference it.
      var inputElement = angular.element( element.children()[1] );

      // This directive should have a set class so we can style it.
      element.addClass( 'edit-in-place' );

      // Initially, we're not editing.
      $scope.editing = false;

      // ng-click handler to activate edit-in-place
      $scope.edit = function () {
        $scope.editing = true;

        // We control display through a class on the directive itself. See the CSS.
        element.addClass( 'active' );

        // And we must focus the element. 
        // `angular.element()` provides a chainable array, like jQuery so to access a native DOM function, 
        // we have to reference the first element in the array.
        inputElement[0].focus();
      };

      // When we leave the input, we're done editing.
      inputElement.prop( 'onblur', function() {
        $scope.editing = false;
        element.removeClass( 'active' );
      });
    }
  };
});

app.controller('ContactsCtrl', function ( $scope ) {
  $scope.contacts = [
    { number: '+25480989333', name: 'sharon'},
    { number: '+42079872232', name: 'steve'}
  ];
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are running into problems because you are misusing angular.

First, a directive should be self-contained, but you are pulling functionality out of it, which makes it **less** universal and **less** reusable. In your code, you have functionality in the DOM and in the controller that belongs in the directive. Why?

Second, it's also unclear from your markup and javascript specifically want you want to accomplish when all these pieces are strung together.

Third, in most cases, directives should have their own isolated scope, which is done by declaring a scope object with attributes it should bind. You shouldn't be passing an expression (i.e. `{{contact.name}}`) inside the directive as it will **break** the binding and your contact will not be updated when the edit-in-place finishes. The proper way is to establish bi-directional binding through an `=` property on the scope. `ng-bind` isn't what you want here: that's scope-specific, so we use it **inside** the directive's scope. As Valentyn suggested, you could do some magic to get around this, but it's not a good idea and it's super-simple to set it up the right way. What's the issue with doing this by an attribute?

This is all bad Ju-ju.

As I pointed out in your [other question on this same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166637/agularjs-how-to-say-to-a-directive-to-clone-scope/14169878), you must make your directive self-contained and work **with** angular, rather than against it. Here's an [attribute-based version of the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/NDFHg/7/) I gave you previously, meeting the first of your requirements. Please let me know what is wrong specifically with this implementation and we can talk about the angular way of fixing it.

Lastly, if you provide further context on what you need in terms of a "button", I'll incorporate that into the fiddle too.

---

**[update]**

It is possible to make the directives work your way, but you will run into problems eventually (or right now, it would seem). **All** components in an angular app (or any app for that matter) should be as self-contained as is feasible. It's not a "rule" or limitation; it's a "best practice". Similarly, communication between directive components *can* occur through a controller, but it shouldn't. Ideally, you shouldn't reference the DOM in a controller at all - that's what directives are for.

If your specific purpose is a **row** that is editable, then **that** is your directive. It's okay to have a lower-level generic edit-in-place directive that the larger directive uses, but there is still the higher-level directive too. The higher-level directive encapsulates the logic between them. This higher-level component would then require a contact object.

Lastly, no, there isn't necessarily a big difference between `ng-bind="var"` and `{{var}}`. But that's not the issue; the issue was **where** that binding takes place. In your example, a *value* was passed to the directive instead of a bi-directionally-bound *variable*. My point was that the directive needs access to the variable so it can change it.

**Summary**: You are coding in a very jQuery-style way. That's great for coding in jQuery, but it doesn't work so well when coding in Angular. In fact, it causes a lot of problems, like the ones you're experiencing. In jQuery, you would, for example, dynamically insert DOM elements, declare and handle events, and manually bind variables all within a single code block, all manually. In Angular, there is a clean separation of concerns and most of the binding is automatic. In most cases, it leads to javascript code *at least* two-thirds smaller than the jQuery alternative. This is one of those cases.

That said, I have created a Plunker that contains a more sophisticated version of both the edit-in-place as well as a new higher-level directive to incorporate additional features: http://plnkr.co/edit/LVUIQD?p=preview.

I hope this helps.

**[update 2]**

These are the answers to your new round of questions. They may be good for your edification, but I already gave you the "angular way" to fix your problem. You will also find that I already addressed these questions (in broader strokes) earlier in my original answer as well as in my update. Hopefully, this makes it more apparent.

*Question:* "Comenting out in the directive: template and scope -> contact.number and contact.name are displayed"

*My Reply:* When you do not specify a scope, the directive inherits its parent scope. You bound and interpolated the name and number *within the context of the parent*, so it "works". Because the directive will **alter** the value, however, this is *not* a good way way to solve it. It really should have its own scope.

*Question:* "Comenting out in the directive: scope -> contact.number only is displayed"

*My Reply:* You bound a scope property of the parent to the "contact.number" directive, so it will get placed inside during the $digest loop - after the directive has been processed. On the "contact.name", you put it *inside* the directive, which can only work if the directive codes for transclusion.

*Question:* "Not commenting out anything -> nothing is displayed"

*My Reply:* Right. If the directive has its own scope (and this one definitely should), then you must use a defined directive scope property to communicate values, as my several code samples demonstrate. Your code, however, tries to use the parent scope in the directive when we explicitly forbid that by using the `scope` property in its definition.

**Summary:** While this second update may be informative (and I hope that it is), it doesn't answer the question *beneath* your questions: how do I use angular components *correctly* so that the scope I'm using is always what I think it is? My first post and the subsequent update, answer that question.

Comment: Can something interesting be said to this page (top) question? I think I already get the 'angular way'.

Comment: I provided working code that I believe meets your requirements along with a fairly detailed explanation. If this does not answer your question, can you restate it succinctly?

Comment: The code u provided is a nice tutorial, bringing nothing new to the table. But I am already very comfortable with the basics of angular and changed my way of writing angular apps dramtically. There are three points ad 1, ad 2, ad 3, in my question, and I am just asking if there is any explanation of that behaviour, so I can mark this question as answered. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is little bit updated your fiddle, but it need further improvements to meet full list of your requirements: http://jsfiddle.net/5VRFE/

Key point is:

```
scope: { value:"=editInPlace" },
```

Some notes: its better to use ng-show ng-hide directivies for visual appearing-hiding instead of changing css classes. Also its better to spread functionality into different directives to have better separation of concerns (check ngBlur directive)

About your confusion of scope check [guide about scopes](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) paragraph "**Understanding Transclusion and Scopes**": Each directive have separate **isolated** scopes, if you want to have access from directive's template to controller's scope use directive scope binging ("scope" field of directive definition object). And also transcluded elements have a scope of from where you defined transcluding template.

From the first view those isolated scope sounds little bit strange, but when you have good structured directives (note also that one directive can require another and share bindings) you can find it extremly usefull.

Comment: I guess, you did not understand my question. Here is the closest I was able to get (http://jsfiddle.net/honzajde/u7tAs/2/). Please read the question from the top. I need to meet some requirements, that are not there just for fun. "edit in placce" attribute's value should be the property on the model that signifies "edit mode" by being watched. I was trying to write a kind of universal directive. You are also not answering my questions.

Comment: There are some restrictions that makes implementation of your idea 'as is' quite hard: ngBind directive replaces content of element, so there is no point of puting something inside element if you have 'ngBind' on it.

So there is a problem of how to get expression which you want to edit? It is easy to do as in my fiddle (edit-in-place='expression'). Other solution could be kind of <div edit-in-place>{{contant.name}}</div>, then use $parse to get setter of inner expression (if possible) and append editing elements using this expression...

Comment: Yes, I was trying to do it this way, since I want to use an attribute to name a property on a controller via that should the instances of the directive communicate. Only, I encountered problems - bindings were breaking... I explained me requirements better in Joshs answer..